# Cas de préposition « de » inutile après « comme » ?

Tags: grammaire, sens, prépositions, ellipse

Dans la phrase suivante « de » apparait d'une façon irrégulière et selon ce dont je peux me rappeler, vraisemblablement entièrement à tort.

- Une bonne hygiène corporelle comme **de** te brosser les dents, **(?)** prendre une douche par jour et **de** garder toujours un corps et des cheveux bien propres, fera aussi l'affaire.

On ne dit pas il me semble « l'hygiène de se brosser les dents » ou « l'hygiène de garder un corps propre » mais quelque chose comme « l'acte hygiénique de se brosser les dents ». Je ne conçois ici  la construction  « comme de » d'aucune des façons habituelles, celles que je connais tout au moins, et je suspecte une relation de complément de nom qui n'existerait pas (le dernier des cinq cas ci-dessous).

**idiomatismes**     comme de juste, comme de bien entendu, il devait forcément apparaître comme de gauche [politique],…
**article**     comme de gentils animaux familiers devenus subitement des bêtes déchaînées
**préposition du verbe**     des négligences dont on parle comme de faiblesses
**reprise en tant que marque de l'ellipse du verbe et du sujet déjà utilisé**
              On parle **de** notre région comme *de* l'exil". (*comme on parle de l'exil*)
             Il en est **des** anciennes fables comme *de* nos contes modernes: il y en a de moraux, qui              sont charmants; il y en a qui sont insipides' […] (*comme il en est de nos*)
**reprise en tant que marque de l'ellipse du nom dans une fonction de complément de nom**
             Le thème de réflexion proposé — le baroque au théâtre et la théâtralité du baroque —              amenait les spécialistes **du** théâtre français comme *de* la tragédie silésienne

Cela signifierait à mon avis ceci.
           Des actes de bonne hygiène corporelle comme te brosser les dents,  prendre une douche            par jour et  garder toujours un corps et des cheveux bien propres, feront aussi l'affaire.

Néanmoins un doute subsiste.
Est-ce que quelqu'un peut confirmer que cet usage est en erreur ?
 Au cas où il n'y a aucune erreur
      -1 quel est le principe grammatical,
      -2 quelle signification particulière apporte cette adition de « de »,
      -3 ou encore, est-ce que cette préposition pourrait être optionnelle ?

Answer (score 1):

> Une bonne hygiène corporelle comme ***[celle]*** de te brosser les dents …

*celle* devient redite pour *comme* … de la pure "toto-logique".

Comment: Cela me semble correct à condition que le pronom « celle » soit utilisé, mais est-ce que l'on peut l'omettre et préserver la correction de la phrase ? Doit-on prendre cette réponse comme une confirmation que la phrase en question n'est pas du bon français ? On pourrait donc dire « l'hygiène de se brosser les dents » ?

Comment: La francophonie n’est pas un concept mais un espace de vie. Du bon français : « Tu as vus les chevals, ils ont courri beaucoup vite » probablement ce genre de phrase que vous avez prononcé en phase d’apprentissage, dans les espaces de la langue d’Oc toujours vivante autour de la  méditerranée … puis cela a été submergé par l’écrit qui passe de l’échange instantané de mots portés par tout le langage corporel, aux concepts écrits, qui interpose l’intellect borné par l’indicible. La phrase remise dans l’oralité, prononcée par quelqu’un qui sait convaincre, est audible et compréhensible par tous …

Comment: … par quelqu’un à la voix mal placée et sans talent, elle risque de sortir par l’autre oreille. Je n’ai aucune expérience des paillasses des laboratoires de langue, disséquer pour rendre un jugement se fait sur des cadavres, loin des ménestrels, troubadours et toute leur descendance. La grammaire contemporaine m’a définitivement fermé la porte au nez … et je l’en remercie :-) —   Supprimer l’obstacle : « Une bonne hygiène corporelle : te brosser les dents … » rend la phrase limpide.

Comment: Un commentaire qui touche une corde sensible dans ma compréhension psychologique du phénomène linguistique : cette remise dans l'oralité me rappelle que dans la  prononciation de rien d'autre que quelques mots banals seul le fait de le faire avec ou sans l'accent régional peut être la différence entre être et ne pas être compris. Il est cependant dommage que je puisse pas tout à fait saisir toutes les abstractions dont vous faites part.

Comment: La psychologie est dépendante des mots qui ne savent dire l'indicible, le théâtre met en œuvres tous les langages du corps dans le présent, alors les mots sont accompagnés du langage des autres sens, et tout s’éclaire lorsque le talent s’exprime dans l’espace magique de la scène.

Comment: En fait, "de" est facultatif après "comme", mais pas superflu : il renforce l'importance de ce qui suit.

Comment: On peut dire "comme faire ceci-cela", mais dire "comme DE faire ceci-cela" amplifie ce qui suit le "de". En tout cas, c'est l'impression que cela me fait.